# Help identifying an encryption accelerator

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, encryption

I believe this was released around 2010.  Pin configuration appears to be 8x8

[image: AA040]
[image: AA040]

I was able to get it hooked up.  Hardware ID:

> PCI\VEN_104A&DEV_7007&SUBSYS_00000000&REV_21

Vendor 104A is indeed STMicroelectronics.  Thank you!

Comment: what research have you done?

Comment: Lots of Googling of the printing, without much result.  I don't work with chips enough to recognize the logo.

Comment: The logo is from STmicroelectronics www.st.com

Comment: possibly a custom chip

Comment: I was able to find a few more tidbits: The Hardware Crypto Accelerator is a cryptographic offload engine that is capable of encrypting data at 3 gigabits per second while maintaining an advanced level of security. 3 gigabits per second seems way beyond a basic STM32 microcontroller's capability. Also it's fabbed on a 65nm process, and is EOL already. https://i.dell.com/sites/csdocuments/Shared-Content_data-Sheets_Documents/en/uk/Dell_Data_Protection_Hardware_Crypto_Accelerator_Data_Sheet.pdf

Comment: Also https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-uk/sln295816/dell-data-protection-encryption-hardware-crypto-accelerator-software-and-hardware-prerequisites?lang=en

Comment: Now I just need to find a Linux driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Help identifying an encryption accelerator*

Some help narrowing down the possible supplier: -

If it isn't a fake device then you should look at ST microelectronics as the likely supplier: -

[image]

If you know the number of pins (unclear in your picture) you might also narrow the search down because it looks like a QFN package like this: -

[image]

Comment: Maybe a STM32L4 in a QFN32 package. Compare power supplies and possible IO pins positions. Some have AES hardware.

Comment: @TEMLIB the OP did indicate that it is an accelerometer type device.

Comment: @Andy_aka. The OP indicate that it is an _encryption accelerator_ type device. No MEMS.

Comment: @TEMLIB OK, I bow to your knowledge in this area.